# Adding alt text and links to MediaWiki's gallery of images

Tags: image, hyperlink, tooltip, mediawiki, gallery

In MediaWiki I want to display a [gallery of images](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aImages#Rendering_a_gallery_of_images) with alt text (tool tip) and a link to another page.

This can easily be done for a [single image](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aImages#Altering_the_default_link_target). Does anyone know how to do this for an image gallery?

Comment: I've accepted my own workaround answer as there was no other. But if anyone comes up with a better solution I can accept theirs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, there is a *workaround*. You can put the images in a table. That way you can use the [ImageMap](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aImageMap) functionality for the link and tool tip. You can also add a row below for the caption (which can also be a link).

So, the code is e.g.:

```
{| style="font-size:85%; border: 2px solid blue;"
|
<imagemap>
File:<image name>|frameless|x80px|center
default [[<link for image>|<tool tip for image>]]
desc none
</imagemap>
|-
|[[<Caption link>]]
|}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you wikis for this great answer. It also works without the imagemap extension if you use this code:

```
 {|
 |[[File:yourpic.png|x200px|link=yourlink]]<br />[[your link|your caption]] || 
 [[File:yourpic2.png|x200px|link=yourlink2]]<br />[[your link 2|your second caption]]
 |}
```

For a demo look at http://www.linuxintro.org